# Input password blank override user password

Tags: forms, symfony, change-password

im developing an user profile section for my app. I have a password field to allow the user change your password.

I have a problem with this. When the user fill the password input, your password are updated correctlly. But when, the user not fill the input, the user password set a blank value.

I like if that user not fill the input, keep the current password.

It is my form definition:

```
$builder
            ->add('email','text',array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('clave','password', array(
                'required' => false,
                'always_empty' => true
            ))
            ->add('reClave','password',array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('telefonos','collection', array(
                'type' => new TelefonoType(),
                'required' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->add('reset', 'reset')
        ;
```

Note: I dont use FOSUserBundle.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you just add a check when you insert password into database? like if(!empty($password)) // insert

Comment: @TejasGosai thanks for reply...i dont think about that. Is a good idea. Thanks !

Comment: Could you post the code of you Action (where you validate the form)? It might have a smarter way to do this using the form framework.

Comment: Welcome!.. But as @maphe suggested, you should use 2 different forms for password and other details.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tejas suggested you, you can check in your `User::setPassword()` function if your param is empty and set it only if it's not. But it's not the best way because you override a form constraint in your entity (the NotBlank constraint on a password).

A better and simple solution would be to display two separated forms on your profile edition page. First for common data, and second for password update. Then you can a [NotBlank](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) constraint on your field, make it `repeated` type ([doc here](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html)) if it's not, also add more constraints like "more than 6 characters" ([Range](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html)) or "at least letters and numbers" ([Regex](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)).

The last solution is to use [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) to control your validation rules according to your form : creation or edition. But it is more complecated to manipulate.